# Java Implementation of a Linked List

Tags: java, list, object, linked-list, model

I'm trying to implement a *linked list* in java consulting my school's textbook.

To vist the list I use the method `getInfo()` for each node that should return name and surname of every person in the list (I'm implementing a list of person).

I don't get why my textbook, in the method `getInfo()` of the class Node, returns a `new Invitato(info)` and not the one who is stored in the class `Nodo`.

If I try to return the one who is stored in the class `Nodo`, I'm getting a null pointer exception.

```java
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        Invitato i1 = new Invitato("Michele","Bianchi");
        Invitato i2 = new Invitato("Paolo","Rossi");
        Invitato i3 = new Invitato("Mario","Verdi");
        Invitato i4 = new Invitato("Giacomo","Neri");

        Lista l = new Lista();

        l.inserisciInCoda(i1);
        l.inserisciInTesta(i2);
        l.inserisciInTesta(i3);
        l.inserisciInPosizione(i4,2);

        l.visitaLista();
    }
}


public class Lista{
    private Nodo head;
    private int elementi;

    public Lista(){
        elementi=0;
        head = null;
    }

    private Nodo creaNodo(Invitato invitato, Nodo link){
        Nodo nuovoNodo = new Nodo(invitato);
        nuovoNodo.setLink(link);
        return nuovoNodo;
    }

    public int getElementi(){
        return elementi;
    }

    private Nodo getLinkPosizione(int n){
        Nodo p = head; 
        int i = 1;

        if(n>elementi || n<1)
            return null;
        else{
            while(p.getLink() != null && i<n){
                p = p.getLink();
                i++;
            }
        }
        return p;
    }

    public void visitaLista(){
        Nodo p = head;
        if(p==null){
            System.out.println("Lista vuota");
        }
        else{
            while(p!=null){
                System.out.println(p.getInfo().toString());
                p = p.getLink();
            }
        }
    }

public void inserisciInTesta(Invitato invitato){
        Nodo p = creaNodo(invitato, head);      //creo un nuovo nodo e lo liko alla testa
        head = p;                             //il nuovo nodo diventa la head
        elementi++;
    }

    public void inserisciInCoda(Invitato invitato){
        if(head==null){                             //se la lista è vuota
            inserisciInTesta(invitato);          //posso inserire il nuovo nodo in testa
        }

        else{
            Nodo p = getLinkPosizione(elementi);            //prendo l'ultimo nodo
            Nodo nuovoNodo = creaNodo(invitato, null);
            p.setLink(nuovoNodo);
            elementi++;
        }
    }

    public void inserisciInPosizione(Invitato invitato, int posizione){
        if(posizione <=1){
            inserisciInTesta(invitato);
        }
        else{
            if(posizione > elementi){
                inserisciInCoda(invitato);
            }
            else{
                Nodo p = getLinkPosizione(posizione-1);
                Nodo nuovoNodo = creaNodo(invitato,p.getLink());
                p.setLink(nuovoNodo);
                elementi++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void eliminaInTesta(){
        if(head == null)    //la lista è vuota?
            return;
        head = head.getLink(); //la nuova head è il nodo a cui linka, quindi ora head riferisce al secondo nodo
        elementi--;
    }

    public void eliminaInCoda(){
        if(head == null){               //lista vuota
            return;
        }
        Nodo p = getLinkPosizione(elementi-1);    //prendo il penultimo nodo
        p.setLink(null);                // e metto il suo link a null
        elementi--;
    }

    public void eliminaInPosizione(int n){
        if(n<=1){
            this.eliminaInTesta();
        }
        else{
            if(n>=elementi){
                this.eliminaInCoda();
            }
            else{
                Nodo pp = getLinkPosizione(n-1);         //nodo prima di quello da cancellare
                Nodo ps = getLinkPosizione(n);          //nodo da cancellare
                
               pp.setLink(ps.getLink());                //assegno al link precedente a quello da cancellare il link di quello che sto cancellando
               elementi--;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Invitato{
    private String nome;
    private String cognome; 

    public Invitato(String nome, String cognome){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public Invitato(Invitato invitato){
        this.nome = invitato.getNome();
        this.cognome = invitato.getCognome();
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCognome(){
        return cognome; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return nome + " " + cognome+";";
    }
}

public class Nodo{
    private Invitato info; 
    private Nodo link;

    public Nodo(Invitato invitato){
        this.invitato = new Invitato(invitato);
        link = null;
    }

    public Invitato getInfo(){
        return new Invitato(info);
    }

    public void setLink(Nodo link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Nodo getLink(){
        return link;
    }    
}
```

Comment: getInfo() is returning a copy of the Invitation in the Nodo. Without seeing the full stack trace of your NPE it isn't possible to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Small tip for the future: write code in English, not Italian. Sure, the code will work anyway, but it gets hard for anyone to read and understand what you do (even for me, and I'm Italian!)

Comment: Does this even compile? In your `Nodo` class constructor you have `this.invitato = ...` but that class does not have any field named `invitato`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of Nodo is incorrect:
`this.invitato = new Invitato(invitato);`
should be:
`this.info= new Invitato(invitato);`

And you don't need to build a new instance of Invitato in Nodo's contructor and in `getInfo` method:

```java
    public Nodo(Invitato invitato){
        this.info = invitato;
        link = null;
    }
    public Invitato getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
```

Once the constructor fixed, I've got a list without any exception:

```
Mario Verdi;
Giacomo Neri;
Paolo Rossi;
Michele Bianchi;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, except for the info and invitato mismatching I was using my textbook approach that didn't make sense to me.